# How do I add a Dictionary<string,string> to an existing JSON.Net's JObject?

Tags: json.net

I've got a JObject (using JSON.Net) that I created by parsing some JSON text. I'm directly manipulating, adding keys at the top level of this JObject. I have no problems when the value I'm adding is a string:

```
json["newkey"] = "New Value"; // works
```

But I'll be damned if I can figure out how to add a Dictionary, e.g.:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict["one"] = "1";
dict["two"] = "2";
json["dict"] = dict;          // fails
```

I've done quite a bit of googling and reading the JSON.Net docs, but everything seems oriented towards reason JSON text into a JObject, or writing .NET objects as JSON text using serialization. Or using some fancy LINQ statements to do all kinds of things with complex objects...

I've tried these and none have worked:

```
json["dict"] = new JObject(dict);
json["dict"] = new JObject((Dictionary<string,string>)dict);
json["dict"] = new JArray(dict);  // desperation sets in :)
json["dict"] = (JObject)dict;     // please dear god let this work
```

Most of the latest errors I encounter are:

**Could not determine JSON object type for type System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String].**

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for something like this:

```
json["dict"] = JObject.FromObject(dict);
```

Comment: Very useful when coding a custom converter that serializes to json

Answer (score -6):

There is a desperate "hack" that you can use, it's not pretty (doing twice the same thing) but it works :)

```
  json["dict"] = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict));
```

Comment: In this case, your json is serialized string, not an object.